# Site does not redirect sub directory to root - drupal 7

Tags: php, .htaccess, drupal, redirect, drupal-7

I installed drupal 7 at http://website.com/subdirectory i want to redirect the sub directory to http://website.com or at least hide the subdirectory path in the url.

I have tried numerous .htaccess codes and even changing the base_url to the root website at sites/default/settings.php to no avail, when i change the base_url to look at the root site the sites skin breaks. Is there someway i can do this?

Comment: Are you using cpanel or any other control panel? you can map [http://website.com] to [/<ABSOLUTE_PATH>/subdirectory] so that it will work.

Comment: Yes i'm using cpanel, do you paste this code in any configuration file?